# How to install NPGSQL and connect a PostgreSQL database to Power BI?

Tags: database, postgresql, powerbi, npgsql

I've read a lot of articles and guides online stating that I need to install this [npgsql program](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases) in order to connect Power BI to a PostgreSQL database. Unfortunately none of them provide instructions on how to actually install it. On the website there are two zip files that come with no installer, so I have no idea how to actually install it.

From the PGAdmin website their instructions are in programming languages that I don't understand. Can anyone please help me out on how to actually install this and connect my database to Power BI and not just send me a link to another website? I only know SQL, I don't have any knowledge of any programming language.

I've tried reading every search result on how to setup this up or install and I can't figure it out.

Comment: You do know what's the solution for not knowing a programming languages, right?